# SharePoint 2013 search - Content processing component is down. How to fix it?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, content

I ran [SRX Report](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2016/02/01/announcing-the-search-health-reports-srx-for-sharepoint-search-diagnostics/) from microsoft and it gave me below information.

> Servers with SSA Components not 'Active': SharePointServer
>      [ContentProcessingComponent1]
>        ServerName: SharePointServer
>        State: unknown
>        Message: Node not found

I didnt find anything else from event viewer logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do the following steps as below to troubleshoot this issue:

Restart the "SharePoint Server Search 15" service.

Make sure there is enough memory and disk space.

Reconfiguring Content Processing Component, follow the steps as below:

http://stevemannspath.blogspot.sg/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-search-adding-new.html

SharePoint 2013 : How to repair a broken Search component at low cost:

http://olivier-richard.azurewebsites.net/2016/05/04/sharepoint-2013-repair-broken-search-service-low-cost/